# JSONPATH:How to filter the array by the length of string filed in objects

Tags: size, jsonpath

JSON

```
   {
        "code":0,
        "success":true,
        "errorMsg":null,
        "data":{
            "list":[
                {
                    "contentId":71687197,
                    "name":"817店铺浏览",
                    "createTime":"2021-08-17 11:41:27",
                    "audiTime":"2021-08-17 12:04:04",
                    "statusName":"使用中",
                    "status":1,
                    "audiStatusName":"审核通过",
                    "audiStatus":0,
                    "contentUrl":"http://market.wapa.taobao.com/app/retail-shop/rax-pi/pages/weex?wh_weex=true&sellerId=2211880772357&shopId=0&bizCode=mcloud",
                    "pageId":"/wireless/decorate?pageId=186699",
                    "templateType":"店铺浏览6秒模板",
                    "reason":null,
                    "tasks":"1629975754101010,1632711553519030,1630668279525055,1631758389579075,1631833251234003,1632367930442084,1631502134666091,1632640663561086,1631270789008004,1630556520622027,1632649453157023",
                    "pages":[
                        {
                            "id":"42b76a87",
                            "type":"close",
                            "label":"关闭页面",
                            "pageId":null,
                            "content":null,
                            "x":537,
                            "y":222,
                            "ftemplate":null,
                            "pageName":null,
                            "title":null,
                            "component":null
                        }
                    ],
                    "openScene":null,
                    "appContentDetail":null,
                    "accountType":null
                }
            ],
            "count":86,
            "type":null,
            "bizTypes":null,
            "taskRules":null
        }
    }
```

I want to filter based on the length of tasks.
This is my attempt.
$...data.list[?(@.tasks.size < 5000)]
$...data.list[?(@.tasks.size() < 5000)]

$...data.list[?(@.tasks.length< 5000)]
aboout this I can succeed on the JSONPATH tool

$...data.list[?(@.tasks.length() < 5000)]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R7C6.png)

Comment: can you be more specific about your question which array are you wana filter inside this json response...?

Comment: I want to select objects by the length of tasks.      $...data.list[?(@.tasks.size < 5000)]    I don't know if it's right to do this.

Comment: JSONPATH is not very detailed in terms of string length

Comment: `$.data.list[?(@.tasks.length<5000)]` should work.  However all implementations might not support. if you are using Jayway try this tool . https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/